# How to resolve git MERGING state?

Tags: git, merge, git-merge

I have a pull request from a source branch to a target branch.

I have run:

```
$> git checkout target-branch
$> git pull
$> git checkout source-branch
$> git merge target-branch
```

There were some conflicts which I have resolved with:

```
$> git mergetool
```

This merge wasn't 100% successful, so I manually removed the conflict artefacts (`>>>>>>` etc) from the files and responding to the prompt:

```
>Was the merge successful? [y/n]
```

with `y`.

So I am happy with the state of all of the files in my source branch, but my CLI now shows:

```
dir/to/my/project (source-branch|MERGING)
$>
```

How do I tell git that I'm happy with the merge I've done?

Comment: Doesn't `git status` give you instructions for committing your merge?

Comment: @Chris, you're right, I've just run that and it does say `(use "git commit" to conclude merge)`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Most likely you need to `git commit` to commit your merge to your local repository.

Comment: You have to do a `git add .` first. Then can do `git commit`, then push changes to your remote. At least that worked for me.